# winRT DataContractSerialized

Tags: c#, windows-8

```
class AppDataManager
{
    public static async Task SaveAsync<T>(T data, string fileName)
    {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, 
            CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);


        var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

        serializer.WriteObject(stream ,data);
        await stream.FlushAsync();
    }

    public static async Task<T> RestoreAsync<T>(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

            var instream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(instream);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

in the MainPage.XAML on a click event.

```
    private async void SaveButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        data = new UserData()
        {
            Name = "ibraheem",
            ID = 1,
            phoneNumber = 799,
            Course = "java"
        };
        await AppDataManager.SaveAsync<UserData>(data, fileName);
    }
```

and when I click the Save button, it gives me the exception

> Type 'DesigningElements.UserData' cannot be serialized. Consider
>   marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all
>   of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute
>   attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types.

Comment: post the code of the UserData class

Comment: The exception's message looks quite clear to me, you have to mark the class and the members with attributes, since `DataContractSerializer` is opt-in, and not opt-out (like the regular `XmlSerializer`).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `UserData` class is declared similar to below

```
[DataContract]
public class UserData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string phoneNumber { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Course { set; get; }
}
```